# How to test your Litecoin mining hash rate?

Tags: litecoin, hashpower

I don't know if there exists a service to quickly check what your mining hash rate is for Litecoin as the following does for Bitcoin

http://bitminter.com/test

I'm looking for something that doesn't require to install or configure anything, or if necessary to do so with the less possible fuss.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to https://litecoin.info/Mining_hardware_comparison and see the hashrate corresponding to the equipment you have, assuming you know what is inside your computer. Actual results may vary, but usually this is a good estimate. Of course, if you overclock, you will get better hashrates, at the cost of increased power usage. If you want to *actually* mine, you will need to register at a mining pool and configure your miner to log in to said pool. The website you linked uses Java code to test hashrates, and this will not give accurate results (even for Bitcoin), as Java is usually slower than machine language.

Comment: So the Java test is useless to test actual mining rates, and nothing beats actually joining a pool and mine? :( I had seen the "mining hardware comparison" page above, since it lists 4 different hash rates for Radeon 7750 (and I understand a number of configurations can modify the rate further) I wanted to get actual numbers without having to install or configure anything.